# Errors installing the perl module File::Scan::ClamAV

Tags: perl, clamav

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Gnome desktop. I'm missing one of the requires for having ClamAV work with SpamAssassin and it will not install, here is the output. The command used to install is:

```
chris@localhost:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for chris: 
root@localhost:~# perl -MCPAN -e shell
Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v2.00)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> install File::Scan::ClamAV


 CPAN.pm: Building J/JA/JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for File::Scan::ClamAV
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/File/Scan/ClamAV.pm blib/lib/File/Scan/ClamAV.pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::Scan::ClamAV.3pm
  JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 CLAMD_PATH=/usr/sbin /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00basic.t ....... ok  
t/01ping.t ........ 1/3 # Failed test 2 in t/01ping.t at line 26
#  t/01ping.t line 26 is: ok($av->ping);
t/01ping.t ........ Failed 1/3 subtests
t/02reload.t ...... 1/3 # Failed test 2 in t/02reload.t at line 25
#  t/02reload.t line 25 is: ok($av->reload);
t/02reload.t ...... Failed 1/3 subtests
t/03quit.t ........ 1/4 # Failed test 2 in t/03quit.t at line 31
#  t/03quit.t line 31 is: ok($av->quit);
t/03quit.t ........ 3/4 ERROR: LOCAL: Socket file /root/.cpan/build/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91-_962_7/clamsock could not be bound: Permission denied
t/03quit.t ........ Failed 1/4 subtests
t/04scan.t ........ 1/8 # Test 4 got: "" (t/04scan.t at line 36)
#   Expected: "1" (Didn't detect /root/.cpan/build/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91-_962_7/testfiles/clamavtest)
#  t/04scan.t line 36 is: ok(exists($results{"$testdir/clamavtest"}), 1, "Didn't detect $testdir/clamavtest");
# Test 5 got: "" (t/04scan.t at line 37)
#   Expected: "1" (Didn't detect /root/.cpan/build/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91-_962_7/testfiles/clamavtest.zip)
#  t/04scan.t line 37 is: ok(exists($results{"$testdir/clamavtest.zip"}), 1, "Didn't detect $testdir/clamavtest.zip");
# Test 6 got: "" (t/04scan.t at line 38)
#   Expected: "1" (Didn't detect /root/.cpan/build/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91-_962_7/testfiles/clamavtest.gz)
#  t/04scan.t line 38 is: ok(exists($results{"$testdir/clamavtest.gz"}), 1, "Didn't detect $testdir/clamavtest.gz");
t/04scan.t ........ Failed 3/8 subtests
t/05streamscan.t .. 1/8 # Test 5 got: <UNDEF> (t/05streamscan.t at line 43)
#   Expected: "FOUND"
#  t/05streamscan.t line 43 is: ok($ans, 'FOUND');
# Test 6 got: <UNDEF> (t/05streamscan.t at line 44)
#   Expected: "ClamAV-Test-Signature"
#  t/05streamscan.t line 44 is: ok($vir, 'ClamAV-Test-Signature');
t/05streamscan.t .. Failed 2/8 subtests
t/pod-coverage.t .. ok  
t/pod.t ........... ok  

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01ping.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
t/02reload.t    (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
t/03quit.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 4 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
t/04scan.t      (Wstat: 0 Tests: 8 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  4-6
t/05streamscan.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 8 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  5-6
Files=8, Tests=29, 53 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys + 49.99 cusr  2.21 csys = 52.25 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 5/8 test programs. 8/29 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 JAMTUR/File-Scan-ClamAV-1.91.tar.gz          : make_test NO

cpan[2]> exit
Terminal does not support GetHistory.
Lockfile removed.

Output of any SA process. In this case I just ran sa-learn --dump magic, errors noted below:
chris@localhost:~$ sa-learn --dump magic
plugin: failed to parse plugin /etc/spamassassin/clamav.pm: Can't locate File/Scan/ClamAV.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Scan::ClamAV module) (@INC contains: lib /usr/share/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl) at /etc/spamassassin/clamav.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /etc/spamassassin/clamav.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/SpamAssassin/PluginHandler.pm line 109.
```

Does anyone know of a method to get this installed? Had no issues on my old Mandriva machine of course that's dead and gone as of last weekend.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact command you ran to install the module. I am guessing you tried to install as a regular user.

Comment: Good idea. I made the changes to the post, as you can see I used the 'sudo' command which 'should' have made the install as root.